# How can I stop and start TGitCache.exe gracefully

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I want to remove my local repository entirely, but TGitCache.exe keeps an open handle to the directory. I would like to shut it down gracefully, delete the folder and start it again.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

1. Open **TortoiseGit Settings** > **Icon Overlays**
2. In section "Status cache" select "None"
3. Click OK

`TGitCache.exe` will disappear from the process list.

[image: icon overlays]

If you need it again, you can turn it on by selecting another option, like "Default". After a click in an explorer window `TGitCache.exe` will run again.

Comment: In the same setting there is also the possibility to exclude a folder

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32427524/3906760 for a quicker way - despite this issue should also be fixed in recent versions.

Comment: This is a huge resource saver, you have no idea.

Answer (score 16):

You can enable a systray icon for TGitCache.

Open TortoiseGit settings and open Advanced page. There set `CacheTryIcon` to `true` and restart TGitCache.

Now you have a new TortoiseGit icon in the systray where you can select "Exit" to close TGitCache (it will restart automatically again). You can also select "Disable Status cache" which will set Status cache to `None` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921151/3906760).

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen this?

https://tortoisegit.org/issue/401

It's a bug report on TortoiseGit that seems to be describing your exact problem.

Basically, it seems that TGitCache.exe shouldn't be doing that, and in the newest versions of TortoiseGit it doesn't. Perhaps you might try upgrading your TortoiseGit?

Comment: I already have the newest version. And I suppose there will be "1 more bug" till the end of time, so graceful shutdown is still a requirement, no matter what. But I have the solution, see my own anser in a minute.

Comment: @Notinlist You are right. Ten years later, I decided to shut the background process down, forever. It makes the already slow windows OS even slower. CPU Maximized by just browsing stuff in the file explorer. It's an endless source of problems. With it gone., things works as normal-slow as usual, and a simple 'git status' gives me the info I need, when I need it.