# arm-linux-androideabi-strip unable to rename

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

Getting the arm-linux-androideabi-strip so many times, with multiple reasons as mentioned below.

reason: File exists
reason: Resource busy

Was not able to get an answer over google or stack overflow (Posts which are posted with similar problem).

Please post the answers below.

Comment: Since this is a Q&A site, when you post a question it should be a question, and when you post an answer it should attempt to provide an answer to the question at hand. What you could do if you ran into a problem that you couldn't find an answer for at StackOverflow but were able to eventually solve anyway, is to formulate a question about the problem you encountered, and then post an answer to it yourself.

Comment: I have restarted computer and all worked fine. Maybe some applications hunged up in the memory or some files became locked.

Answer (score 2):

if you are getting error saying arm-linux-androideabi-strip unable to rename and reason as file exists and resource busy like that, please observe that some Tortoise version of the resource keeper (Ex: TGitCache.exe) is running the processes, try killing it or [stopping it gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773257/how-can-i-stop-and-start-tgitcache-exe-gracefully), then try building again. It will succeed. It could be anyother resource keeping process as well and most of the times its repositories softwares.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue in Feb. 2016, on a very small native shared library build, while my big .so projects worked for years without any problems. It seems to be some kind of race condition int the command arm-linux-androideabi-strip (or i686-linux-android-strip, whatever abi you're building). The strip command tries to replace the original .so file with the stripped one, before it actually closes the original file, I guess. None of the answers found here or in other technical posts worked well for me. The build might have worked right in about 20% of cases, while giving me the *[...]-linux-androideabi-strip unable to rename* error in 80% of builds. Wasted the whole afternoon and evening on this issue...

#### My workaround:

Modified the cmd-strip macro in the file [android-ndk]/build/core/default-build-commands.mk as follows (see comments with my name):

```
# The strip command is only used for shared libraries and executables.
# It is thus safe to use --strip-unneeded, which is only dangerous
# when applied to static libraries or object files.
# GKochaniak, at the end of next line added: -o $(call host-path,$1).strip 
cmd-strip = $(PRIVATE_STRIP) --strip-unneeded $(call host-path,$1) -o $(call host-path,$1).strip
```

Now the build, instead of one *libMyShared.so* produces two files in the final install directory: *libMyShared.so* (orignial, un-stripped) and *libMyShared.so.strip* (stripped). We only need to delete the original and rename the stripped file. I did this by modifying [android-ndk]/build/core/build-binary.mk (same folder) as follows:

```
$(LOCAL_INSTALLED): $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE) clean-installed-binaries
    $(call host-echo-build-step,$(PRIVATE_ABI),Install) "$(PRIVATE_NAME) => $(call pretty-dir,$(PRIVATE_DST))"
    $(hide) $(call host-install,$(PRIVATE_SRC),$(PRIVATE_DST))
    $(hide) $(PRIVATE_STRIP_CMD)
# GKochaniak added 2 lines below:   
    rm $(PRIVATE_DST)
    mv $(PRIVATE_DST).strip $(PRIVATE_DST)
```

**Note**: as I work on Windows, I had to put into into my system path the Cygwin *bin* folder with rm.exe and mv.exe commands, as the paths in this make file use forward slashes, so it was a problem when I tried to use del, ren commands.

Greg