# Tortoisegit Windows Shell Overlay Wrong

Tags: tortoisegit

At times, the TortoiseGit Windows shell overlay is wrong, indicating modifications when there are none.

The cleanup command looks too heavy handed, none of the Clean Type options are appropriate and will remove needed files.

Is there any other way to force TortoiseGit to update the shell overlay?

Comment: When you say "modifications when there are none", do you mean they show the red symbol but if you try a Commit there are no files shown as changed?  Is this on a few specific files or is it every file in the repo (ie Explorer using the wrong icon)?

Comment: The shell shows the red symbol, but there are no files to commit.

Answer (score 1):

There might be several reasons why the overlay icons are wrong.

One common reason is if filenames differ in casing (even if NTFS disregards casing, Git still honours it, even if core.ignoreCase is set; cf. https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2980).

If this is not the case, try to restart TGitCache (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32427524/3906760) or try to use another overlay handler (Shell or Shell Extended; cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay).

Answer (score 0):

I have found that sometimes Windows Explorer is slow to update the status of a file e.g. still showing uncommitted changes even though all changes have been committed. Refreshing the display by hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> or choosing Refresh from the right-click menu usually fixes it.
[image]